# WP Allimport mapping taxonomies, categories need to be able to ignore some entries

Tags: mapping, taxonomy, wpallimport

I've got a wp all import working fine except one part which I cannot find a way around.
In the taxonomies section I have Amenities. There are multiple amenities in the feed.
I map each one that comes in e.g. "A/C", "Air Conditioning" maps to "Air Con". "Pool", "Swimming Pool", "Private Pool" all map to "Pool Private". All works fine.
What I want to do is ignore some amenities. e.g. if amenity is "Security" I don't want to import it. I have tried mapping "Security" to a blank field but it still adds "Security".
I need to map it to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work with multiple terms, but try to put this code here prnt.sc/1186ewb

```
[IF({Amenities[1][.="Security"]})][ELSE]{Amenities[1]}[ENDIF]
```

Be sure to change "Amenities" with your item name

You can also add other terms using AND/OR in the function

Or you can also use this https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/code-snippets/#mapping-values

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with multiple terms. I'm just going to map ones I don't want to a catch all amenity.